# Ruby on Rails expiring cache fragments with submit to remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to expire cache fragments in a submit_to_remote method. The problem is that the method submit_to_remote calls doesn't expire the cache fragment. I was wondering if expiring fragments through ajax is different some how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete the content of your page without do it in javascript or refresh the page.

So if you expire the fragment cache is do in your server not in your client.

Comment: How would I do it in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Is your cached fragment living outside of the container that gets updated after successful submit_to_remote? If so, you would of course  have to refresh the page as the cache lives on the server side & the fragment is in the browser world.

Comment: Yeah, the fragment is in a different view, but if an action occurs elsewhere I need to expire the fragment. In my rjs template I do a page.reload, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why doesn't `page.reload` work? Could you show us some of your controller code?

Comment: Hey, here's some of the code: View: <% cache(:action => 'show', :part => 'users_profile_updates') do %> Controller: expire_fragment(:controller => 'profiles', :action => 'show', :part => 'users_profile_updates') The method I'm calling the expire_fragment in uses an rjs template, which has page.reload in it.